# Easiest way of submitting your website to various search engines

Tags: search-engines

A few months ago I saw a video where someone explained a website where when you submit your link, it would be submitted to all mayor search engines. It looked like a pretty nice website.

I thought I would remember it but as always I forget both what the link was, I also forget where I saw the clip.

Does anyone know such a website, or an easy tool to submit your website in various places.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do submit any new sites I create to search engines, but I don't do it through the "old" method of just submitting a URL (such as [here on Google](http://www.google.com/addurl/?continue=/addurl)). Instead I create an [XML sitemap](http://www.sitemaps.org/) and I then go to each search engine's webmaster management console and submit the site. I also include the path to the sitemap in the robots.txt just to make sure for those that don't have consoles or ones I haven't submitted the site to.

URLs for the 3 major search engines webmaster management console:

- Google https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/
- <strike>`Yahoo http://siteexplorer.search.yahoo.com/`</strike>
- Bing http://www.bing.com/webmaster/

Text to put in the robots.txt:

```
Sitemap: http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml
```

I also often ping the search engines to let them know a new sitemap is available. This site has a little page where you can submit your sitemap to a bunch at once, although it no longer works for Google: http://www.sitemapwriter.com/notify.php

Of course, all this said, if there aren't links to your site then all of this is useless. Getting an account on sites like Twitter, Facebook, YouTube can be helpful in getting links to your site, especially if you post useful links/content.

Answer (score 1):

These days submission to search engines isn't important anymore. Google and others crawl the web on it's own.

Comment: If there are no links to your site, there is no way for Google to find it.

Comment: Yes is makes sense that if you have your link all over the net that search engine submission is not needed any more. But sometimes I start off with a brand new website with a brand new domain name. If I can submit the link it would speed up the process just a bit.

Comment: If there are no links to your website than Google won't think that your website is trustworthy enough to be shown to it's users.

Comment: it will usually show without any incoming links, it will just be ranked very poorly.

Answer (score 0):

These are the two I see out there:

- http://www.addme.com/
- http://www.freewebsubmission.com/

Comment: Thank you, addme.com looks like a nice website with some nice links. I will check this one out.

Comment: I wouldn't trust any automated submission service, since all the major search-engines reject automated submissions (which is why they all use captchas). Most of these are just trying to re-sell so-called SEO services to the naive.

Answer (score 0):

Submitting your site to search engines does nothing. The only reliable way to get indexed in search engines is to get links pointing to your site.

Even a single link should get your site indexed, so look out for web directories (such as [dmoz.org](http://www.dmoz.org/)) or find some forums that are related to your niche and post a link (if they allow advertising - otherwise put it in your signature and join in the conversation).

Depending on the site you can also do a bunch of real-world advertising and press releases, then you might get links from news sites and blogs.